# css animate not working properly on internet explorer

Tags: css, jquery-animate

I am just trying this and it is not working properly on internet explorer 11.

not look like cube at all. how can i achieve like in chrome?

```
<a href="https://codepen.io/afarrar/pen/edwNWP"> Check here </a>
```

Please guide me

Thanks

Comment: where is your css

Comment: i edited my question. It is my first time asking here so too many errors. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe IE has issues with keyframes, transform, etc.
Please check which CSS properties are not supported here: 
https://caniuse.com/